# Recaptcha validation fail: please check the captcha

Tags: php, recaptcha

The relevant form:

```
     <script language="JavaScript" src="gen_validatorv4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
   <div id="contactform">
            <div id="details">
        <form method="POST" name="contactform" action="contact-form-handler.php"> 
            <p>
                <label for='name'>Full name *:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="name">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for='address'>Address *:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="address">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for='unit'>Unit:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="unit">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for='postal'>Postal code *:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="postal">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for='email'>Email:</label> <br>
                <input type="text" name="email">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for='phone'>Telephone *:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="phone">
            </p>
             <p>
                <label for='date'>Preferred pickup date* :</label> <br>
                <input type="date" name="date">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for='time'>Preferred timeslot* :</label><br>
                <span id="small">Please provide us with a 2 Hr time slot<br> (10% discount if we don't make it in time <strong>after we agreed</strong> on a timeslot</span><br>
                <input type="text" name="time1"> to <input type="text" name="time2">
            </p>
            </div>
            <div id="products">

            <p><label for='itemsharp'>Items for sharpening:</label><br>
                <textarea name="itemsharp"></textarea>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for='itemrepair'>Items for repair:</label><br>
                <textarea name="itemrepair"></textarea>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for='comment'>Comment: </label><br>
                <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
            </p>
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="[mysitekey]" data-theme="dark"></div>
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
        </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The php:

```
<?php 
$errors = '';
$myemail = '[aperfectlyvalidemailadress]';//<-----Put Your email address here.
if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
   empty($_POST['email']) || 
   empty($_POST['address']) ||
   empty($_POST['postal']) ||
   empty($_POST['date']) ||
   empty($_POST['time1']) ||
   empty($_POST['time2']) ||
   empty($_POST['phone']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: fields with a * are required";
}


$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$address  = $_POST['address'];
$postal = $_POST['postal'];
if(!empty($_POST['unit'])){
    $unit = $_POST['unit'];
}
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$time1 = $_POST['time1'];
$time2 = $_POST['time2'];
$itemsharp = $_POST['itemsharp'];
$itemrepair = $_POST['itemrepair'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email_address))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Please provide a valid email address";
}

       $captcha;
        if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
          $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        }
        if(!$captcha){
          echo '<h2>Please check the captcha form.</h2>';
          exit;
        }
        $secretKey = "[mysecretkeyisfilledinhere]";
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
        $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
        if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
          echo '<h2>You are spammer ! Get the @$%K out</h2>';
        } else {

if( empty($errors))
{
    $to = $myemail; 
    $email_subject = "Sharpening request: $name";
    $email_body = "You have received a new sharpening request. ".
    "From:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email_address \n Phone: $phone \n Address: $address $unit $postal \n \n Date: $date \n Between: $time1 and $time2 \n Items for sharpening: $itemsharp \n Items for repair: $itemrepair \n Comment: \n $comment "; 

    $headers = "From: request@sharpsteel.ca\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    //redirect to the 'thank you' page
    header('Location: requestthankyou.html');
} 
        }
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Request failed</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- This page is displayed only if there is some error -->
<?php
echo nl2br($errors);
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Most of this is cobbled together from various sources. My php is not that strong.

I tested it when I first created it, it worked fine.

Now the site is live and.... nothing. Any attempt to submit the form leads to the "please check the captcha" error page. I didn't change a thing, which is why I'm getting a touch frustrated.

I've obscured the email address and secret key here, for obvious reasons.

I have looked at other questions but they're either not relevant (using different and unfamiliar to me languages) or I simply don't understand for which I do apologise.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: do you see any errors in the console? Are all the files loading ok ( again, look for 404 errors in net console )

Comment: I can see some wayward html markup in your form ~ the way you use div tags within and around the form makes it not valid narkup

Comment: @RamRaider No 404 errors. I agree the div tags are weird, but they're for positioning purposes. I wanted it in two columns rather than one long form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were definite markup issues with the html form- there were div tags breaking the form.

The markup below appears identical but rest assured the prder of the form and div tags has changed to ensure the form is vald.

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="gen_validatorv4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<div id="contactform">
    <form method="POST" name="contactform" action="contact-form-handler.php">
        <div id="details">
            <p>
                <label for='name'>Full name *:</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="name">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for='address'>Address *:</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="address">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for='unit'>Unit:</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="unit">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for='postal'>Postal code *:</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="postal">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for='email'>Email:</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="email">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for='phone'>Telephone *:</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="phone">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for='date'>Preferred pickup date* :</label>
                <br>
                <input type="date" name="date">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for='time'>Preferred timeslot* :</label>
                <br>
                <span id="small">Please provide us with a 2 Hr time slot<br> (10% discount if we don't make it in time <strong>after we agreed</strong> on a timeslot</span>
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="time1"> to
                <input type="text" name="time2">
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="products">
            <p>
                <label for='itemsharp'>Items for sharpening:</label>
                <br>
                <textarea name="itemsharp"></textarea>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for='itemrepair'>Items for repair:</label>
                <br>
                <textarea name="itemrepair"></textarea>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for='comment'>Comment: </label>
                <br>
                <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
            </p>
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="[mysitekey]" data-theme="dark"></div>
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
            <br>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: So weird. That fixed it. Guess I messed up while fiddling with the layout. Thanks so much!

Comment: no problem - just remember if the markup isn't valid there are likely to be layout problems and unforseen issues when submitting forms